# How to identify series and parallel connections of capacitors in complex circuits?

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

[image]Like for this question (picture attached) how to identify if capacitors are in series or in parallel?

Comment: Yes it is. Edited just now.

Comment: Note that in general, the rules of series and parallel circuit elements don't suffice (because there are networks that can't be deconstructed in terms of only parallel or series constructions). General networks require the use of [Kirchhoff's rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws).

Answer (score 0):

Those batteries and capacitor are all in series. The current will follow through them one after each other.

If they were in parallel, the current could take two different paths (hence the parallel part).

Keep in mind that if you were to extend the circuit, this would change. But as it is, from the viewpoint of each battery, the two capacitors (and other battery) are in series.

This circuit simplifies to a 16 V source applied to a 3F and 5F capacitor in serie. This splits the voltage 10 V and 6 V (5 eighth and 3 eighth) between them, which is how they pick two of the multiple choice answers.